# .sh ffmpeg works manually, not with CRON

Tags: command-line, video, cron, ffmpeg, avconv

I make a movie from jpeg pictures with the script:

```
#create movie
ffmpeg -i /home/philippe/Dropbox/Public/Cheiron/day/%d.jpg  -r 25 -q:a 5 -pix_fmt yuv420p /home/philippe/Dropbox/Public/Cheiron/day/movie.mp4
```

It works fine from terminal, but not from cron (using scheduled tasks).

What is weird is that a similar script NOT using ffmpeg but avconv, works fine both manually and with cron:

```
#create movie
avconv -f image2 -i /home/philippe/Dropbox/Public/Cheiron/day/%d.jpg -r 25 -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p /home/philippe/Dropbox/Public/Cheiron/day/movie.mpeg
```

What's wrong with my ffmpeg script through cron?

Comment: When I open a terminal, and run: avconv -f image2 -i /home/philippe/Dropbox/Public/Cheiron/day/%d.jpg -r 25 -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p /home/philippe/Dropbox/Public/Cheiron/day/movie.mpeg  I have to confirm the overwriting of the old movie, and it runs fine. Now, for some reason, it does not run with cron. Here are the cron entries. The one is job 5:  MAILTO=""
PATH=/opt/gutenprint/sbin:/opt/gutenprint/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/u$
SHELL=/bin/bash
* * * * * /home/philippe/Scripts/datestamp.sh # JOB_ID_2
*/15 8-20 * * * /home/philippe/Scripts/cheiron_movie.sh # JOB_ID_5

Comment: NB: authorization for the script cheiron_movie.sh is 755.  PPS: many other scripts in same folder run fine

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you supply the full path for the `ffmpeg` and `avconv` commands. You can get this by running `which`, e.g., `which ffmpeg`.

I don't have either of those programs installed on my server but I suspect that `avconv` is in the `PATH` used by `cron` while `ffmpeg` isn't.

Comment: I tried, but still the same. It actually does the same (now!?!...) with avconv:  The new script being:           #create movie                                                /usr/bin/avconv -i /home/philippe/Dropbox/Public/Cheiron/day/%d.jpg -r 25 /home/philippe/Dropbox/Public/Cheiron/day/movie.mp4

Comment: @PhilippeP Can you edit your question to also include both your crontab entries and how you run the script from your interactive shell? If you're running the jobs as a shell script, it would need to include the script interpreter and the script would have to be executable.

Answer (score 0):

Oops...
I forgot -y in my bash script, so it was endlessly waiting for the authorization to overwrite the previous file.
Sorry.

Hopefully, this mistake will be helpful to others.
;-)

Comment: Hi Philippe, since you've found the solution to your problem, you should [accept one of the answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to inform others that your issue is resolved. Welcome to the Stack Exchange network!